# Parallization of different instances in a R6class

Tags: r, oop, parallel-processing, doparallel, r6

I am asking for help to design a specific R6class and especially to design a `run` method to would run processes in parallel. Note that all of the code example listed below have not been tested and most likely contain errors. They are just here to help convey how I am thinking about implementing the parallelization of the jobs within my R6Class.

---

I built a R6class type of object called `Input` that is a wrapper for a simulation platform. The goal of the class is to ease the writing of individual set of paramers for inputs to the simulation platform. It might look like

```
input = Input$new()
input$set_parameter_x(...)
input$set_parameter_y(...)
```

I would like the class to be able to directly run the simulations (with the `run` method) and do so with a defined number of threads but I am not sure how to best achieve that goal. Note that each process started by `run` is single threaded. However, I would like that each process started by `run` can run in parallel of call to method `run` made from a different instance of the class `Input`. Something like

```
input_1$run(executable = "/path/to/executable", maxNbThreads = 4)
input_2$run(executable = "/path/to/executable", maxNbThreads = 4)
input_3$run(executable = "/path/to/executable", maxNbThreads = 4)
input_4$run(executable = "/path/to/executable", maxNbThreads = 4)
```

would all run in parallel. I don't know much about paralization in R (hence my question) but of course one could do

```
foreach (input_index = 1:nbInputs) %dopar%
{
    require(myPackage)
    input = Input$new()
    input$set_parameter_x(...)
    input$set_parameter_y(...)
    input$run(executable = "/path/to/executable", maxNbThreads = 1)
}
```

instead but I'd wish that the work of parallelizing the processes would be taken into account by the R6class `Input` and not by the user of this class.

I am thinking about having a vector called `runningThreads` shared among all instances of the class (a static attribute of the class) using an environment (as explained [here](https://r6.r-lib.org/reference/R6Class.html)). `runningThreads` would contain the pid's of the currently running jobs. Then, everytime the `run` method is called, the user would specify the maximal number of threads (`maxNbThreads`) and, in a while loop it would remove from `runningThreads` the pid's of jobs that are not active anymore until the length of `runningThreads` is shorter than the argument `maxNbThreads` provided to `run`. `run` would then run the job and add its pid to `runningThreads`. The public method `run` (and private methods hat `run` would call) might look something like

```
isAThreadAvailable = function(maxNbThreads)
{
    for (thread_index in 1:length(private$runningThreads))
    {
        thread = private$runningThreads[thread_index]
        if (!isThreadRunning(thread))
        {
            private$runningThreads = private$runningThreads[-thread_index]
        }
    }

    return (length(private$runningThreads) <  maxNbThreads)
}


isThreadRunning = function(thread)
{
    return (system(paste("kill -0", pid), intern=TRUE))
}

run = function(exec = defaultExecutable, maxNbThreads = 1, sleepTimeInSec = 2)
{
    stopifnot(maxNbThreads > 0)

    if (maxNbThreads == 1)
    {
        # Then just run it and wait for it to end
        system(paste(exec, paste(private$data, collapse=" ")))
    } else
    {
        while (!isAThreadAvailable(maxNbThreads))
        {
            Sys.sleep(sleepTimeInSec)
        }

        newThread = system(paste(exec, paste(private$data, collapse=" "), "&; echo !#"), intern=TRUE)

        private$runningThreads = c(private$runningThreads, newThread)
    }
}
```

Does it sound like a good method? There are probably packages that could ease the building my R6class. Would you be so kind as to point me to these packages and maybe show a small example of how it could be used for my `run` method in my R6Class?

Comment: You may be interested in processx: https://github.com/r-lib/processx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the package `processx` that @HongOoi mentionned in a comment I could implement what I needed. I did in a very similar style as I designed before but the `processx` package made everything so much easier.

Here is the code for the `run` method

```
 isAThreadAvailable = function(maxNbThreads)
    {
        while (private$shared$isOtherProcessCheckingThreads)
        {
            Sys.sleep(0.001)
        }
        private$shared$isOtherProcessCheckingThreads = TRUE

        thread_index = 1
        while (thread_index <= length(private$shared$runningThreads))
        {
            thread = private$shared$runningThreads[[thread_index]]
            if (!thread$is_alive())
            {
                private$shared$runningThreads = private$shared$runningThreads[-thread_index]
            } else
            {
                thread_index = thread_index + 1
            }
        }

        r = length(private$shared$runningThreads) < maxNbThreads
        private$shared$isOtherProcessCheckingThreads = FALSE
        return(r)
    },


    run = function(exec = "SimBit", maxNbThreads = 1, sleepTimeInSec = 1, waitEndOfThread = FALSE)
    {
        stopifnot(maxNbThreads > 0)
        stopifnot(sleepTimeInSec >= 0)

        while (!self$isAThreadAvailable(maxNbThreads))
        {
            Sys.sleep(sleepTimeInSec)
        }

        newThread = processx::process$new(exec, paste(private$data, collapse=" "))


        private$shared$runningThreads = c(private$shared$runningThreads, newThread)

        if (waitEndOfThread)
        {
            while (newThread$is_alive())
            {
                Sys.sleep(sleepTimeInSec)
            }
        }
    }
```